# rainbow parenthesis in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to install the following feature in vim:
https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow

I did exactly what the manual installation says. I copied the file rainbow.vim to ~/.vim/plugin and added the sentence:

> let g:rainbow_active = 1

to .vimrc file. However, when I try to source the .vimrc file, I get an error:

> syntax: command not found
>   bash: let: g:rainbow_conf: syntax error in expression (error token is ":rainbow_conf")

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

BTW, I didn't install Vundle. That's why I used the manual installation.

Comment: Does it work if you install the plugin globally for all users into path `/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin`?

Comment: I moved the rainbow.vim file to the directory /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin, sourced the .vimrc, and still got the same error.

Comment: Can you try the command `RainbowToggleOn` after opening a file.

Comment: Why don't you try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues)?

Comment: @ap0 , I typed :RainbowToggleOn inside vim and I got the following errors:

rror detected while processing function rainbow#toggle..rainbow#hook:
line    1:
E712: Argument of extend() must be a List or Dictionary
E488: Trailing characters
line    9:
E712: Argument of extend() must be a List or Dictionary
Error detected while processing function rainbow#toggle..rainbow#hook..rainbow#load:
...

Comment: It is hard to tell where your problem is. Which platform are you on and what version of vim do you use? I am using the plugin too. But I installed it through vundle. I am not getting any errors. Maybe, as mMontu said, you should try the issue tracker.

Comment: The error message `syntax: command not found bash: let: g:rainbow_conf: syntax error in expression (error token is ":rainbow_conf")` seems to mean that something is run by bash. WTF ?

Comment: I typed "source .vimrc" and this is the error that I got. However, I did exactly what the instructions say, opened vim and I don't see the rainbow parenthesis :-(

Comment: I think I found the answer. I only had to activate it by typing :RainbowToggle.

Comment: Do you know how to make vim commit the :RainbowToggle command automatically when vim is loaded?

Comment: The answer is that the following statement has to be added to .vimrc: 
autocmd VimEnter * RainbowToggle